# simple css question regarding image align

Tags: css

I want to align my images similar to this page: http://nymanssnickeri.se/

My content div is 900px wide. As you can see, image #1 and #3 are located at the edge of the content div. On this page margin is only used on the image in the middle. If there wasnt more than 3 images, i could use first-child selector on the first image and the problem would be solved. But sometimes there will be multiple rows of images. Any ideas how to accomplish this in a good way? Thanks

Comment: Do you know the size of your images every time?

Comment: Are specifically you against using a table to display this data, which is in some respect tabular?

Comment: @Dutchie432, I disagree that it's tabular in any semantic way.

Comment: Yes i know the size, but forgot to mention that the amount of images may vary

Comment: @zzzBov, You would disagree that a 'layout' with 3 columns and X rows is, as I stated, "in some respect tabular"? Ok then.

Answer (score 0):

You can give every image equal horizontal margins, and then on the first and last, add a class and have `margin-left: 0` and `margin-right:0`, respectively. You'll have to play with the margin size / math a bit to get it right.

Example:

```
#container img { margin: 0 20px; }
#container img.first {margin-left: 0; }
#container img.last {margin-right: 0; }
```

20px is just a random number I chose. It depends on your image sizes, and how many you have.

Edit:

Math for the margins (check this, just made it up on the fly):

(total container width - total width of all images ) / (total number of images - 1) * 2

Answer (score 0):

If the layout is known ahead of time, including number of photos, etc. You could use a table:

```
<table width="900"><tr><td><img /></td><td><img /></td>
<td><img /></td></tr></table>
```

Or you could use a div, and concatenate these to create multiple rows:

```
<style
div#img-container { width: 900px; }
div#img-container img { display: block; }
img.lft { float: left; }
img.mid { margin: 0 auto; }
img.rgt { float: right; }
</style>
<div id="img-container">
<img class="lft"/>
<img class="mid"/>
<img class="rgt"/>
<br />
</div>
```

You might need to reset margins, paddings and borders to 0 on the images to use this method, otherwise the images will overflow slightly and not align correctly.

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt really answer my question. This would display 3 images next to eachother. What im after is the middle image to be centered while the ones to the left and right sticks to their edges.

Comment: @fille I updated the answer to more gracefully handle conditions where the images are not the same width.  `margin: 0 auto;` is the CSS preferred way to <center>

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have three images per row and not have to worry about setting pixel margins to achieve the effect you can do something like this...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ENQTZ/1/

```
<div>
    <span class="a"></span>
    <span class="b"></span>
    <span class="c"></span>
</div>
<div>
     <span class="a"></span>
     <span class="b"></span>
     <span class="c"></span>
 </div>
```

```
div {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
span {
    display: block;
    width: 32%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.a {
    float: left;
}
.b {
    float: right;
}
.c {

     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     position: relative;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<center> 
<div ID="Content" Style="Width:900px"> 
  <center>
     <table>
        <tr>
           <td>
              Your image here
           <td>
           <td>
              Your image here
           <td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
              Your image here
           <td>
           <td>
              Your image here
           <td>
        </tr>
     </table>
  </center>
</Div>
</center>
```

Any of this useful to you? This is my template that I use. just add more td tags for more cells, and more tr tags for more rows of images.

Further, You can style your images to the exact size they need to be, but be careful that stretching / squashing might occur

```
<img ID="Image" src="Image/Cat.png" alt="Cat.png" style="Width:50px;Height:50px" />
```

Comment: ok that thumbs down was just mean. im also just trying to help -.-

Comment: Sorry but I had to -1 this for use of the `center` tag, it's obsolete in HTML5 and has been deprecated for over a decade. Don't take it personally though, everyone gets voted down at some point :-).

Comment: I really didnt know :( I use it very often and it works fine for me over many browsers.

Comment: It works, but since it's not supported anymore, there is a possibility that it could stop working in the future as browsers get upgraded. CSS is much better for centering content now :).

Comment: well <div style="Margin-left: auto; Margin-Right: auto" /> also works :P for centering. I think :?

Comment: <div style="margin: 0 auto;"> for shorthand, and it requires the width being set, usually. but ya.